# How can I pull all input "<select>"s from a table and populate an array?

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have it fairly close but the order is all wrong. The output is all messed up at the moment and I can't seem to add all the rows to the array.

```js
$('#clicker').on('click', function(e) {
  var tableToObj = function(table) {
    var trs = table.rows,
      trl = trs.length,
      i = 0,
      j = 0,
      keys = [],
      obj, ret = [];

    //       j += 1;
    for (; i < trl; i++) {
      if (i == 0) {

        for (; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
          var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
          if (sel.length == 0) {
            keys.push(trs[i].children[j].innerHTML);
          } else {
            keys.push(sel.val());
          }
        }

      } else {

        obj = {};
        for (j = 0; j < trs[i].children.length; j++) {
          var sel = $(trs[i].children[j]).find("select");
          if (sel.length == 0) {
            obj[keys[j]] = trs[i].children[j].innerHTML;
          } else {
            keys.push(sel.val());
          }

        }
        ret.push(obj);
      }

    }
    return ret;
  };

  document.getElementById('r').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(tableToObj(document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>FirstColumn</td>
    <td>SecondColumn</td>
    <td>ThirdColumn</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
        <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
        <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
        <option value="tr4">tr4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
        <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
        <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tr3 row</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>
      <select>
        <option value="tr1">tr1</option>
        <option value="tr2">tr2</option>
        <option value="tr3">tr3</option>
        <option value="tr4">tr4</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>tr4 row</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<button id="clicker">Button</button>
<br /> Result:
<div id="r"></div>
```

Here is the output I get:

```
[{"SecondColumn":"1"},{"FirstColumn":"tr3 row","SecondColumn":""},{"FirstColumn":"tr4 row","SecondColumn":"","ThirdColumn":""},{"FirstColumn":"0","SecondColumn":"1","ThirdColumn":"0"},{"FirstColumn":"0","SecondColumn":"1","ThirdColumn":"0"}]
```

This does not change upon changing the select value. I'm very confident the issue is with the var `sel` within the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two things to address:

1. In order to get the value of the `select` tags you should change the two instances of `sel.val()` to `sel.find('option:selected').val()`.
2. To fix the ordering issue you need to update `keys.push(` to `obj[keys[j]] =` in the else portion of the row loop  (when i > 0)

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/camurv7o/1/)